# Excel Highlight Rows which contains

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a short question about Excel. I have to find words in a Excel-sheet with many rows. So I need to search for multiple words at a time. With the normal filter and the search function it is not possible to search for more then one word.

The words I have to search for are like this: "AA2454, AA43242, AA9595"

Comment: What do you mean by search? As in filter by multiple criteria? Or enter 3 different values and find any of them?

Comment: I will describe you. I've a list with many words (5k). I have another list with around 1k words. I need find all the 1k words in the 5k excel sheet and after that, i have to remove the rows.

Comment: is your 1 k words list just a string with words delimited by coma or it's a column in excel? If it's a column you can do a vlookup @marc-hofstetter

Comment: I can format them to be sepereated or like this |... what ever

Comment: in your 5K, add a column to do a vlookup on the 1K something like `=VLOOKUP(A1, Sheet2!A:A, 1, FALSE)` , then `Z>A` sort on the new and you will be left with a long list of `#N/A` at the top, and just delete them.

Comment: Or delete the ones that are not `#N/A` depending on which data set you want.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below formula in conditional formatting to highlight all rows which contains the required strings that you have mentioned,

```
=OR((COUNTIF(1:1,"AA2454")>0),(COUNTIF(1:1,"AA43242")>0),(COUNTIF(1:1,"AA9595")>0))
```

Let me know if its not working

Comment: the thing is, i have to type in every 800 word in the formula. This is'nt what i'm looking for. Sorry